# Matching a single character within a string in R

Tags: r, grepl

Im assert if there is a "." in a string in R, but grepl always comes back false. Can anyone explain where im going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
grepl("testtxt",".")
[1] FALSE
grepl("test.txt",".")
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need either `fixed = TRUE`

```
grepl("test.txt", pattern = ".", fixed = TRUE)
#[1] TRUE
```

NOTE: `pattern` is the first argument of `grep/grepl`  If we specify it in different order, make sure to name the parameter

or escape (`\\.`) the `.` as `.` is a metacharacter that matches any character